# Java GUI sloppy after two seconds

Tags: java, performance, swing, user-interface, windowbuilder

I am struggling with Eclipse WindowBuilder GUI. I've made a layout and it does work, but it begins to lag after 2-3 seconds and is horribly slow. I've googled it, found the `revalidate()`, `validate()`, `update()` and stuff like this, but it does pretty the same. Can you please point me out where it gets laggy, hence I don't know what causes me this and I'm confused a lot now.

Source code:

```
package forum;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class ForumView {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField txtUsr;
private JTextField txtPasswd;
private JSeparator separator;
private JTextField txtUsr_1;
private JTextField txtPasswd_1;
private JButton btnNewButton_1;
private JSeparator separator_1;
private JButton btnNewButton;
private JButton btnNewButton_2;
private JButton btnNewButton_3;
private JButton btnAddPicture;
private JButton btnNewButton_4;
private JButton btnBack;
private JButton btnSortAlphabetically;
private JButton btnNewButton_5;
private JLabel lblNewLabel;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ForumView window = new ForumView();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
                window.frame.update(window.frame.getGraphics());
                window.frame.revalidate();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public ForumView() {
    initialize();

}

public void redrawMethod() {
    frame.repaint();
    txtUsr.repaint();
    txtPasswd.repaint();
    btnNewButton.repaint();
    separator_1.repaint();
    separator.repaint();

    txtUsr_1.repaint();
    txtPasswd_1.repaint();
    btnNewButton_1.repaint();
    separator_1.repaint();
    btnNewButton.repaint();
    btnNewButton_2.repaint();
    btnNewButton_3.repaint();
    btnAddPicture.repaint();
    btnNewButton_4.repaint();
    btnBack.repaint();
    btnSortAlphabetically.repaint();
    btnNewButton_5.repaint();
    lblNewLabel.repaint();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1318, 814);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    txtUsr = new JTextField();

    txtUsr.setBounds(10, 11, 86, 28);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtUsr);
    txtUsr.setColumns(10);

    txtPasswd = new JTextField();

    txtPasswd.setBounds(10, 42, 86, 28);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtPasswd);
    txtPasswd.setColumns(10);

    btnNewButton = new JButton("Login");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(txtUsr.getText());
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(106, 10, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    separator = new JSeparator();
    separator.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
    separator.setBounds(205, 11, 2, 51);
    frame.getContentPane().add(separator);

    txtUsr_1 = new JTextField();
    txtUsr_1.setText("usr");
    txtUsr_1.setBounds(217, 11, 86, 28);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtUsr_1);
    txtUsr_1.setColumns(10);

    txtPasswd_1 = new JTextField();
    txtPasswd_1.setText("passwd");
    txtPasswd_1.setBounds(217, 42, 86, 28);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtPasswd_1);
    txtPasswd_1.setColumns(10);

    btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("register");
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(313, 10, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

    separator_1 = new JSeparator();
    separator_1.setBounds(10, 73, 1282, 2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(separator_1);

    btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Add topic");
    btnNewButton_2.setEnabled(false);

    btnNewButton_2.setBounds(10, 120, 100, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);

    btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("Passwd change");
    btnNewButton_3.setEnabled(false);
    btnNewButton_3.setBounds(10, 154, 100, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_3);

    btnAddPicture = new JButton("Add picture");
    btnAddPicture.setEnabled(false);
    btnAddPicture.setBounds(10, 186, 98, 26);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnAddPicture);

    btnNewButton_4 = new JButton("Logout");
    btnNewButton_4.setBounds(106, 43, 89, 26);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_4);

    btnBack = new JButton("Back");
    btnBack.setEnabled(false);
    btnBack.setBounds(10, 223, 98, 26);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnBack);

    btnSortAlphabetically = new JButton("Sort Alphabetically");
    btnSortAlphabetically.setEnabled(false);
    btnSortAlphabetically.setBounds(10, 257, 98, 26);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnSortAlphabetically);

    btnNewButton_5 = new JButton("Add Comment");
    btnNewButton_5.setEnabled(false);
    btnNewButton_5.setBounds(10, 294, 98, 26);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_5);

    lblNewLabel = new JLabel("No Photo");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(420, 11, 55, 51);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
    frame.validate();
    txtUsr.validate();
    txtPasswd.validate();
    separator.validate();
    txtUsr_1.validate();
    txtPasswd_1.validate();
    btnNewButton_1.validate();
    separator_1.validate();
    btnNewButton.validate();
    btnNewButton_2.validate();
    btnNewButton_3.validate();
    btnAddPicture.validate();
    btnNewButton_4.validate();
    btnBack.validate();
    btnSortAlphabetically.validate();
    btnNewButton_5.validate();
    lblNewLabel.validate();

    }
}
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
Now the "main" GUI works, but everything else is freezing. I used an openfiledialog to open a image file, but that dialog freezes out too. Here is the code I've tried:

```
btnAddPicture.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            frame.createBufferStrategy(2);
            frame.validate();
            frame.repaint();
            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            //RepaintManager.currentManager(fc).setDoubleBufferingEnabled(true);
             System.out.println(RepaintManager.currentManager(fc).isDoubleBufferingEnabled());
            //returns true
            //fc.repaint();
            // in response to a button click:
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();

            } else {
                System.out.println("Open command cancelled by user.");
            }
        }
    });
```

EDIT 2:
On Linux machine everything works like a charm.

Comment: some basics (related or not): a) never-ever do any manual locating/sizing of components, that's the exclusive task of the layoutManager b) all done correctly, there's rarely any need to call repaint/re-/validate c) hands off component.getGraphics! BTW, there's a decent tutorial referenced in the swing tag wiki :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested that code, and it works fine for me. The window is opened for about 2 minutes and everything works as it should. When does lag begin? When clicking buttons? Moving the window?

Comment: the lag begins when I don't do anything...the GUi is painted, buttons are working, but after 2 seconds they aren't repainted...and yes, it lags when I move the window...it's kinda hard to explain

Comment: Every JFrame I created is built up like yours. Have you tried more simple GUIs? Are 3rd-person applications working without problems?

Comment: I compile. After that, window comes out. I can do whatever I want for that two seconds, but after that the gui is not updating, but I can write to textboxes, or push buttons (despite they don;t react on that)...so basically it looks like the program works, but are not updated

Comment: in java, nope...I work with java, but I needed only the "console" input and stuff...now I was coerced to use user interfaces and they are like hell in java, cause in C# it works like a charm

Comment: I made some changes in your main method, try this: http://ms330.nitrado.net:4444/ForumView.java

Comment: I've tried this, but no success, but thanks for that thread stuff :)

Comment: freezes also after two seconds :/

Comment: Then it seems that your problem is somewhere else. It also works like a charm by me, have you made experience with other GUI applications written in Java? Try updating your graphics driver, java version?

Comment: already at the newest version, so is the graphics driver. Is there some log what I can find to tell me more of the problem?

Comment: Try this: http://ms330.nitrado.net:4444/Test.jar

A simple and dirty-coded application for testing, with a simple indicator. Source: http://ms330.nitrado.net:4444/source.java

Time should keep updating!

Comment: thanks, you was right...maybe there isn't problem with code...your little program froze also like my program...

Comment: I googled for that, but found no results. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: 1.8.0_20-ea is the java version

Comment: java version "1.8.0_20-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-ea-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b05, mixed mode)

to be more precise

Comment: What you can do next is considering about downgrading to Java 7/U51.

http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=83395

And then go to Eclipse, right-click your project -> Properties -> Java Build Bath -> Libraries -> select JRE System Library -> click on Edit -> select Alternate JRE -> click Installed JREs... -> click Add -> Standard VM -> select the home directory, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\`, and then mark the jre7 as current, Hope that works

Comment: nothing, after these instructions the problem is still persistent

Comment: Is the new jre applied? You can try it out like this:

`public static void main(String[] args)`
`    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));

Comment: yes, it is set to 1.7...1.7.0_51 is the number from java

Comment: That makes me despaired. What about rebooting your machine? or... try an other OS if available? Are you using Win/UNIX/Mac?

Comment: windows 8.1 and rebooted, yet reinstalled eclipse/java/amd drivers and stuff, still nothing

Comment: What you could do:

- Check your PC for viruses
- Boot your PC in safte-mode (?)
- Play with JFrame settings (double-buffering, RenderingHint etc.)

Comment: DUDE!!! how can I repay you this favor? IT FRIGGING WORKS!!! doublebuffering was the thing that made it working!

Comment: I am glad it works. Repay? No. I am even proud about that green hook left to the question :P

Comment: yup, it worked, but as I figured it out yet, it works only on the "main" gui...when I open a dialog (warning dialog, or open file), it (the dialog) works same as it worked (freezes if I open the dialog, but the main gui works just fine now)

Comment: The reason is that those dialogs are not double-buffered. So the problem is not Java, it is your pc. But for developing... I think it is ok. But I have never had this problem, and as I said: It's a non-Java problem.

Comment: how can I hard set double buffering?

Comment: I don't know if this is even possible, maybee JVM arguments can also change the behaviour of the frames.

Comment: would you kindly point out some point where to start on that, please?

Comment: No, sorry. I do not know much about that, that was just an idea. What I would also try is completely uninstalling your drivers, and then re-install them.

Comment: that was done previously, but thanks nonetheless, you helped me a lot :) may the Force be with you!

Comment: I have seen, it is working now with Linux. I am happy for you that it works now!